# Why there is no dead-lock in the following thread-safe stack implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <exception>
struct empty_stack: std::exception
{
    const char* what() const throw();
};
template<typename T>
class thread_safe_stack
{
private:
    std::stack<T> data;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    stack(){}
    stack(const stack& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
        data=other.data; 
    }
    stack& operator=(const stack&) = delete;
    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        data.push(new_value);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack(); 
            std::shared_ptr<T> const res(new T(data.top()); 
            data.pop();
        return res;
    }
    void pop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // #1
        if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
        value=data.top();
        data.pop();
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        return data.empty();
    }
};
```

**Question** How can the `data.empty()` return in the following statement,

```
if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
```

given the `void pop(T& value)` has locked the `mutex` already `#1`.

/// Updated ///

Here is my understanding,

`#1` already lock the mutex and will release when the `pop(T&value)` returns. Now in the middle of this function, the code calls `data.empty()` which in turn locks the `mutex` again. Since the mutex has been locked, so the function `empty` cannot get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a call to `std::stack::empty`, not `thread_safe_stack::empty`.  So it isn't trying to acquire the mutex a second time.